# How to set the id attribute of HTML element dynamically with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, rest, thymeleaf

Lets say I have an object : ${object}

and I have the following form:

```
<form id="{{'myForm' + object.id}" class="some class"
      th:action="@{/doSomething}" method="post">
    ....
</form>
```

My goal is to set the id = "myForm1" if we assume that the object.id is '1'.

PS: The way I wrote it's working on Angular JS.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You have to use th:id attribute:

```
<form th:id="'myForm' + ${object.id}" class="some class" th:action="@{/doSomething}" method="post">
// *** Other code here ***
</form>
```

Comment: how to use <lable for ../> for an element with dynamic id?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can use dynamic id with label:

```
        <th:block th:with="randomId=${#strings.randomAlphanumeric(10)}">
            <input type="checkbox" th:id="${randomId}">
            <label th:for="${randomId}"></label>
        </th:block>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is still another (nice) way to accomplish this.

Assuming you are iterating a list of items as shown below, you can use the following `th:id` to set the id using the index of the item being iterated.

```
<th:block th:each="item : ${list}">
  <div class="tab-pane active" th:id="@{|#div-id-${itemStat.count}|}"></div>
</th:block>
```

This example sets an id on a `<div>`. Note that `itemStat` is a fixed name given the iterator name as `item`.

Comment: This really helped me to solve my problem when i was using in Div but can you please tell me what is that th:id overall expression doing?

Comment: @MadhavaraoKulkarni the `th:id` will be converted to a normal HTML `id` attribute in the rendered page. This only allows you to use **Thymeleaf** constructs to iterate and build your page.
The first line in my HTML page is `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` to allow the use of `th` as a prefix in the **Thymeleaf** tags.